# Numpy and spare matrix, how to get what would be the first row in dense

Tags: python, numpy

I have a spase matrix called X.  How to I get the sparse first row, second row etc...

So, I know there should be 100 rows.

How do I do this loop?

```
 for i in xrange(10):
          X[i] = row I want
```

The row I want should also be sparse format.

Thanks

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`X[i]` *is* the row you want. It will be in sparse form already (although it would probably help if you've made it a `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`). Typically we iterate over the rows of a matrix without the index, as simply:

```
for row in X:
    do_stuff(row)
```

although if the index is necessary you can also write:

```
for i, row in enumerate(X):
    do_other_stuff(i, row)
```